# Bootstrap4 - Image outside screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a responsive page, where I got columns placed as follows:

[image]

My code looks as follows:

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="col">...</div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">...</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

But when I try to scale it down, so that the columns go under each other, the image gets out of the screen, looks like this:

[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `col-md-6 col-sm-12` and see... 
and add `row` class into your 2nd col div..

why u just write `col-sm`? did you really know how to use bootstrap?

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
       <div class="w-100"></div>
       <div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```